# Why degree of a proper map is not a homotopy invariant on noncompact manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology

I have read GTM218 Pg466, which argues that the degree of a proper map is not a homotopy invariant by showing the maps $F,G: \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ given by F(z)=z and G(z)=z^2 are homotopy but have different degrees. But I'm wondering how does the compactness act in the proof of the degree of a map on the compact manifold is a homotopy invariant.
I have a proof below:
Since F is homotopy to G, then the induced map from $H^2_{dR}(\mathbb{C})$ to $H^2_{dR}(\mathbb{C}) F^{*}=G^{*}$. So for any 2-form w, $F^{*}w-G^{*}w=dv$, where $v$ is a 1-form. Let $k=degF$ and $t=degG$, we have $\int_{\mathbb{C}}F^{*}w=k\int_{\mathbb{C}}w$ and $\int_{\mathbb{C}}G^{*}w=t\int_{\mathbb{C}}w$. With Stokes theorem, we have $\int_{\mathbb{C}}(F^{*}-G^{*})w=\int_{\mathbb{C}}dv=\int_{\partial\mathbb{C}}v=0$
, I know this proof must be wrong, but what's the mistake?

Comment: I think it's empty, so the integral must be zero.

Comment: The Stokes' theorem I know assumes a compact, oriented manifold with boundary.  This is not $\mathbb{C}$.  Maybe there's some other version you're applying?  Either way, you should include this in your question.

Comment: I check GTM218 again. On page 411, I see the author says that if the boundary is empty, we can interpret the integral on the boundary to be zero.

Comment: I agree, but this assumes the manifold is compact.  Unless you're using a different version of the theorem.....

Comment: There are versions without compactness, but they make assumptions on the forms you can integrate (and maybe these are violated in your case?).  I don't really know, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: I think the issue comes from what one means by “homotopy invariance”: if you mimic the proof that classical de Rham groups are homotopy-invariant, the analog for de Rham cohomology groups with compact support could be invariance under *proper* homotopies (ie proper smooth maps $[0,1] \times M \rightarrow N$). What givea some credit to this theory is that the “obvious” homotopy $(t,z) \in [0,1] \times \mathbb{C} \longmapsto (1-t)z+tz^2 \in \mathbb{C}$ is not proper in this sense: the pre-image of $0$ contains $(t,-(1-t)/t)$ for every $t>0$.

Comment: I agree with your opinion. But if we just focus on my proof, what's wrong with it?

Comment: Based on your opinion, I have an idea that maybe dv is not compact supported. Do you think it is right?

Comment: If you look at it in the $1$-dim case of $\mathbb{R}$, you're asking for an improper integral to converge to $0$.  That's rare.

Comment: This problem has been talked about in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4198921/why-does-stokess-theorem-for-manifolds-without-boundary-not-work-for-int-ax

Comment: To satisfy the compactness, we can only get f to be zero on the boundary.